# Grafana/InfluxDB Geolocation Query. Time spent in city/district?

Tags: geolocation, grafana, influxdb, home-assistant

Trying to use geo-location of my home assistant to create a bar chart of how much time I have spent in a city/district.

So far, I was only able to make the below progress, which should give me some time metric of how much time I spent in city/district.

I cannot figure out how to get from here to a bar chart though. I need the sum of all rows and then a column which shows the time per row relative to the time sum of all rows.

How can I achieve that? And display it all in a bar chart?

[image: grafana]
[image: transformation]